# Fire a function on an item press in Openui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to fire "handleRowPress" when I press a table item.
This is my code:

```
showTable: function(){


    var oData=convertDataTable(testDataInput);

    //make sure table id suffix is set (this is necessary for personalization)
    var oTable = new sap.m.Table('testTable', {
        headerToolbar: new sap.m.Toolbar({
            itemPress: "alert('pippo')",
            content: [
                new sap.m.ToolbarSpacer({})
            ]
        })/*,
        columns: oData.cols.map(function (colname) {
            //make sure column id suffix is set
            return new sap.m.Column(colname, { header: new sap.m.Label({ text: colname })});
        })*/
    });


    oTable.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData));

    for(var i=0; i<oTable.getModel().getProperty("/cols").length; i++){
        oTable.addColumn(new sap.m.Column(oTable.getModel().getProperty("/cols")[i], { header: new sap.m.Label({ text: oTable.getModel().getProperty("/cols")[i] })}));
    }

    oTable.bindAggregation("items", "/items", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells: oTable.getModel().getProperty("/cols").map(function (colname) {
            return new sap.m.Label({ text: "{" + colname + "}" });
        })
    }));

    //oTable.setProperty("selectionChange","handleRowPress");
    //oTable.setProperty("itemPress", "handleRowPress" );
    //oTable.setProperty("select", "handleRowPress" );

    oTable.attachItemPress("handleRowPress");

    var myPage=this.byId("pageOperation");
    myPage.addContent(oTable);

},


handleRowPress : function(){
    console.log("clicked on item!!!!");
    //console.log(event);

}
```

Why can't I do it?
If I try to set the property "itemPress" (comment lines) it doesn't seem to set it.

How can I set the function without an XML view but only with `js` code?

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24361565/1969374) to your other question. You have to declare a ListMode to your Table or a ListType to your items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the handler in the table-constructor as function:

```
var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
    itemPress: function(){
        console.log("clicked on item");
    }
});
```

or set it in the constructor as reference

```
var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
    itemPress: this.handleRowPress
});
```

or attach the function over the created Table-object

```
oTable.attachItemPress(this.handleRowPress);
```

Comment: try to debug the entire code, it can be that the function will not be set because there is another error

Comment: I try to set the function to fire into xml view 
`<Table xmlns="sap.m"
        id="myTable"
        select=""
        selectionChange=""
 swipe=""
 growingStarted=""
 growingFinished=""
 updateStarted=""
 updateFinished=""
 itemPress="function(){ console.log('clicked on item'); }">
    
  <items> <!-- sap.m.ListItemBase -->
     
  </items>
    
  <columns> <!-- sap.m.Column -->
     
  </columns>
</Table>`
But not work..

Comment: if I use 
`console.log(tablePippo.getProperty("itemPress"));`
inside the controller it returns
`Uncaught Error: Property "select" does not exist in Element sap.m.Table#operationDetail--testTable`

Comment: Please note that `itemPress` was introduced in UI5 version 1.20 so make sure to have the latest version in your project.

Comment: where i can see the version? i retrieve from th web the libraries!
src="https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"

Really this is the problem??

Comment: It's just a possible problem. Check the Version in your running application pressing CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S

Comment: the version is 1.20.7
This is My view http://pastebin.com/Qs88E8Gs
`tap="retrieveData"` on the form work but `itemPress="retrieveData"` not work.
And this is the controller http://pastebin.com/fwCVhTpw