# How to handle the itemPress of sap.m.Table?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I've written an XML view. Inside it there is a table:

```xml
<Table xmlns="sap.m"
  id="myTable"
  select=""
  selectionChange=""
  swipe=""
  growingStarted=""
  growingFinished=""
  updateStarted=""
  updateFinished=""
  itemPress="console.log('clicked on item')"
>
  <columns>
    <!-- sap.m.Column -->
  </columns>
  <items>
    <!-- sap.m.ListItemBase -->
  </items>
</Table>
```

I insert the row to the table using the `onInit` of the controller, but when I click on a row, the message is not shown.

If I use `console.log(tablePippo.getProperty("itemPress"));` inside the controller, it throws

> Uncaught Error: Property "itemPress" does not exist in Element sap.m.Table#operationDetail--myTable

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This really seems to be a frequent issue people face when they use `sap.m.ListBase` related controls. Let me give you an overview on how to manage the events (and particularly activate them at all):

The confusion could be related to the `sap.m.ListMode` of controls inheriting from `sap.m.ListBase` and the `sap.m.ListType` of items inheriting from `sap.m.ListItemBase`.

Let's assume the following sample List:

```xml
<List
  selectionChange=".onSelectionChange"
  itemPress=".onItemPress"
  delete=".onDelete"
>
  <items>
    <ObjectListItem
      title="Hello ListItem"
      press=".onObjectListItemPress"
    />
  </items>
</List>
```

### sap.m.ListMode [(Sample)](https://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListSelection/preview)

If you're using `sap.m.List` or `sap.m.Table`, event firing depends on the `mode` you're using. Unfortunately, a List / Table without a `mode` property will **not** fire any event from its side! If you want the List / Table to fire those events, you have to assign to it a mode. For example:

```xml
<List
  mode="SingleSelect"
  ...
>
```

These are the possible modes from the [`sap.m.ListMode` documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.ListMode):

#### None (default)

Since no `mode` property is assigned, **none of the events will be fired!**

> [image: List mode None]

#### SingleSelect | SingleSelectLeft

A list control with `mode="SingleSelect"` shows a radiobutton on the right side of each item and will fire the `onSelectionChange` event as soon as the user clicks on the given radio button control. Using `"SingleSelectLeft"` just moves the radio button to the left side of the item.

> [image: List mode SingleSelectLeft]

#### SingleSelectMaster

A list control with `mode="SingleSelectMaster"` will show you the hand on mouseover and fires the `onSelectionChange` in case of a click on an item.

> [image: List mode SingleSelectMaster]

#### MultiSelect

A list control in `mode="MultiSelect"` offers a checkbox and fires the `onSelectionChange` event on every check **and** uncheck of an item.

> [image: List mode MultiSelect]

#### Delete

Using the list in `mode="Delete"` gives you a nice delete button and fires `onDelete`.

> [image: List mode Delete]

---

### sap.m.ListType [(Sample)](https://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListItemTypes/preview)

There's one more property you should have a look at: The `type` property of your items.

Every item inherits from `sap.m.ListItemBase` and thus has an attribute called `type`. Let's see how it looks like:

```xml
<items>
  <ObjectListItem
    type="Active"
    press=".onObjectListItemPress"
    detailPress=".onDetailPress"
    ...
  />
</items>
```

There are these types listed in the [`sap.m.ListMode` documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.ListType):

#### Active

Depending on the `mode`, the `itemPress` of the list **and** `press` of the list item can be fired. The selected item gets highlighted so the user can see what's selected.

> [image: Item type Active]

#### Detail

A detail button (with icon `sap-icon://edit`) is offered which fires the `detailPress` event.

> [image: Item type Detail]

#### DetailAndActive

As the name says, this is a combination of Detail and Active type. So you have the detail button firing `detailPress` on button click, and the item itself firing the list event `itemPress`.

> [image: Item type DetailAndActive]

#### Navigation

The items have a navigation like look, and `itemPress` and item's `press` are called.

> [image: Item type Navigation]

#### Inactive

No item event gets called from the item itself.

---

Now let's take a look at your problem. You should either assign your Table control a `mode` or assign your items a `type`. After that change the events should get fired.

Generally I would avoid using a `ListMode` and a `ListType` at the same time since there can be unexpected behavior but check it by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Add **type="Active"** to ColumnListItem

```
...
<items>
    <ColumnListItem type="Active">
        <cells>
            <Text text="{Name}"/>
        </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
</items>
...
```

Yang Wang: https://scn.sap.com/thread/3697995

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution using sap.m.CustomListItem

Use set the properties of the ListItem to

type="Active" press="listPress"

```
<List items="{/results}"> 
<items>
<CustomListItem type="Active" press="listPress">
<content>
<VBox>
    <FlexBox direction="Row" justifyContent="SpaceBetween" alignItems="Start">
        <items>
            <Text text="{PernrName}" />
            <Text textDirection="RTL" text="{Document Status}" class='subtext'/>
        </items>
    </FlexBox>
    <FlexBox direction="Row" justifyContent="SpaceBetween" alignItems="End">
        <items>
            <Text text="{Date}" class='subtext'/>
            <Text textDirection="RTL" text="{Current Processor}" class='subtext'/>
        </items>
    </FlexBox>
</VBox> 
</content>
</CustomListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define myItemPress member function in the controller for the XML view and reference it as

```
itemPress = "myItemPress"
```

[See example](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/explored/index.html#/code/sap.m.sample.ListDeletion%20sap.m.List)

Comment: :-/ not work...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324822/fire-a-function-on-press-item-openui5/24326701?noredirect=1#comment37603719_24326701

Answer (score 0):

Another problem in OP's code is that itemPress is used on the level of Table instead of the level of ListItemBase. This will indeed fire click events (if `type="Active"` is set for the ListItemBase element, as explained in other answers here). BUT: The context of the events will not allow to derive the clicked row in the list! So you get an event, but you will not be able to tell from which item it came.

Here is what needs to be changed to identify the clicked row in OP's example, using ColumnListItem as an example for ListItemBase:

Instead of...

```
<Table
    ...
    itemPress="onItemPressed"
>
    <items> 
        <!-- sap.m.ListItemBase -->
    </items>
    <columns>
        <!-- sap.m.Column -->
    </columns>
</Table>
```

... use this:

```
<Table
    ...
>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem 
            type="Active"
            press="onItemPressed"
        >
        ...
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
    <columns>
        <!-- sap.m.Column -->
    </columns>
</Table>
```

To derive the model path of the clicked row you can now use code like this:

```
onItemPressed: function (oEvt) {
    var sModelPath = oEvt.getSource().getBindingContext('myModelName').getPath();
    var sDiD = this.getView().getModel("myModelName").getProperty(sModelPath + "/myModelFieldName");
}
```

You can also add a customData node within the CustomListItem that holds row specific information and access it's key value pairs in the event handler through something like this:

```
var aCustomData = oEvt.getSource().getCustomData();
```

But again:
Both approaches will only work if onItemPressed is called on ListItemBase 
 / ColumnListItem level!