# sap.m.Table selection single select mode without radio buttons

Tags: sapui5

When we set `mode="SingleSelect"`, radio buttons are displayed. How can we hide radio buttons from each row?

```xml
<Table id="idDetailTable"
  growing="true"
  selectionChange="vendorSelect"
  includeItemInSelection="true"
  mode="SingleSelect"
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all checkout [Tims awesome summary of sap.m.ListModes here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327875/how-to-handle-the-itempress-of-a-table/24361565#24361565). Secondly here is your code:

```
<Table id="idDetailTable"  
       items="{tabledata>/Items}" 
       height="100%" 
       growing="true" 
       selectionChange="vendorSelect" 
       includeItemInSelection="true"   
       mode="SingleSelectMaster" 
       modeAnimationOn="false">
```

Check [sap.m.ListMode](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListMode.html) for more details.

Btw: The string values of ANY UI5 enum is equal to the last part of its namespace: sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelectMaster -> SingleSelectMaster. That's why you can use just that last part in an XMLView or HTMLView.