# Event "press" on sap.m.CustomListItem doesn't work

Tags: javascript, sapui5

The [dokumentation of sap.m.CustomListItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.CustomListItem.html) says that CustomListItem hat a `press` event.

I created a site with the press event on a list item, and another press event on a Button inside the list item. The button works fine. A click on the list item shows nothing. Not even an error.

```
var oCustomItem = new sap.m.CustomListItem({
    content: [
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "{text}"}),
        new sap.m.Button({
            text: "btn",
            press: function(){
              alert("Pressed the button");
            }
        })
    ],
    press: function(){
      alert("Clicked the list item");
    }
});
```

Here is an example:
http://jsbin.com/pozeve/4/edit?html,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a frequent issue people face when they´re using List controls. There´s an answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24361565/1969374).

To put it in a nutshell, you either have to add a `type` property to your `CustomListItem`:

```
var oCustomItem = new sap.m.CustomListItem({
    content: [
        new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{text}"}),
            new sap.m.Button({
                text: "btn",
                press: function(){
                    alert("Pressed the button");
                   }
                })
            ],
            type : sap.m.ListType.Active,
            press: function(){
              alert("Clicked the list item");
            }
});
```

or a `mode` property to your `sap.m.List`. For a comparison see the answer mentioned above.