# No event is firing in CustomListItem

Tags: javascript, list, listitem, sapui5

With reference to: [Event “press” on sap.m.CustomListItem doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525384/event-press-on-sap-m-customlistitem-doesnt-work),
I've tried the same solution , but the press event isn't fired.

```
<List growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" id="employeeMasterList" includeItemInSelection="true"
    items="{path: '/EmployeeSet'}">
    <items id="employeeMasterListItems">
        <CustomListItem id="employeeMasterListItem" type="Active" press="onSelect">
            <Label text="Test" />
        </CustomListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

In the controller I have the following method:

```
onSelect: function(oEvent) {
    console.log("onSelect", oEvent);
}
```

With Type `DetailAndActive` I can fire the `detailPress` event, but nothing else.

Any idea?

Sorry for duplicate post. Unfortunately, I can not add a comment to the mentioned question due to missing reps.

Comment: You can try to use the `selectionChange`- or `itemPress`-Event from the List that contains the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding `sap.m` to the `data-sap-ui-libs` inside my `index.html`. It seems to be that the events of sap.m controls are not properly fired if the library is not preloaded.

`<script src="resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js"
         id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
         data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons, sap.m
         data-sap-ui-appCacheBuster=" ...and so on... >"
</script>`

Answer (score 2):

Check the [documentation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.ListItemBase/events). The press event is not fired if **includeItemInSelection** is set to true. You might also have a look at this fine [compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24361565/1969374) of information.