# SAPUI5 Table- Disable entire row based on some status when loading value from ODATA

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am using a SmartTable. SAP UI5 library version is 1.52.15

My requirement is, I need to disable row selection (entire row including checkbox) of the SmartTable based on some row status when loading value from ODATA (model).

I am writing the code in "dataReceived" event of the smart table .

But not sure which method will disable the entire row.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! Whar did you try so far, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an internal table, something like the this [official example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable.mtableDataState/code).

As soon as you defined the internal table, then you can play with `<Table>` to disable the entire row you need to define a [mode](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListMode) for the interior table.

```js
<Table mode="None" ...>
```

More example also can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327875/how-to-handle-the-itempress-of-sap-m-table)